# Android Theme.Holo not working

Tags: android, themes

i am trying to get my app to use the theme "Theme.Holo", which is the dark theme for android. my app minimum SDK is 9, and i have the Support libraries included from google.

i had my app working with the dark theme, and i have no idea what i changed, now its only light. and ic ant seem to change it.

this was my button before (i want this):

[image: Dark]

And this is what i have now:

[image: Light]

This is my values/res/styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

and this is my res/values-11/styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

and res/values-14/styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Manifest part that relates to theme,

```
   <application 
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
```

At this point i have no idea why the buttons are showing up as Light theme, i tried Theme.Black as well, it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

as @FD_ pointed out Holo theme is available on ICS and above. I suppose the emulator/device you are testing against has SDK < 11.

If you need backward compatibility for holo theme use [HoloEveryWhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) library by Prototik.

Comment: Emulator and device are 4.4.2.

Comment: I just set the min SDK to 11, then 13, and still the excat same. Light colored buttons, i had the Dark button working before. i have no idea what i changed in my project that converted it to Light.

Answer (score 0):

To use `Theme.Holo` you have to use at least `API Level 11`. Please refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#SelectATheme) link in the Android Developer Guide.
Try to change the minimum API-Version to 11 in you Android Manifest and it should work.

Comment: The OP has posted styles used for specific api level (separate styles for v11 and v14). It is sufficient if the target apk is set to the latest so that the api is compiled against it. I don't think it is necessary to change min SDK version.

Comment: I changed Min SDK, and it had no effect. so you are correct about the separate styles. I am fine with the Old gray android button for older devices.